# How to write a DataFrameGroupBy object to an Excel File?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame df.

```
 xl = pd.ExcelFile("filename.xlsx")
 df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0])

 grouped = df.groupby(['A'])
```

I want to write 'grouped' back to an Excel file. grouped is not a DataFrame, rather it is a

```
pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000C7178D0
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the `groupby` object? A `groupby` object is like metadata describing how to perform the groupby until you perform an operation to it it won't return you an aggregation. Are you just wanting to just sort by 'A'?

Comment: No, I have duplicate values in column A, I was attempting to group them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698424/how-to-work-with-duplicate-entries-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: I want to ultimately achieve this, so I was trying to use groupBy